# get value from stem graphic

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

let us suppose that we have following graph of singular value distribution

[image]

which was given by following command

```
stem(SV)
```

SV_singular values,from visually of course we can find approximate values of  singular values,but is there any possibility to get  values  from graph itself?of course someone may say that if we have SV,we can directly access,but i want  just graphicl tool to get it from picture itself,for example like this

```
b=stem(SV);
```

but  when i type b,i am getting following number

```
b

b =

  174.0051
```

it is matlab self learning,so please help me to learn how to find values from graphics in matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stored in your variable `b` is a handle to the current axes. You can access the properties of this axes using `get`. To access the values in the plot, you can use

```
b=stem(SV);
values = get(b, 'ydata');
```